# Iterate over associated array data for matched element using Lodash

Tags: lodash

Is there a way in lodash to find a matching name (assumes unique) and iterate over an array of associated locations i.e. initially return the array bit of the matched element (filter? pickBy? etc.) and iterate over that.

```
var locations = [ {name:"dave", location:["home","work","pub"]},
                  {name:"alice", location:["school","college","university"]},
                  {name:"fred", location:["us","uk"]} ];
```

Search for "fred", should return:

```
0:us
1:uk
```

I can do it with _.filter and nested _.forEach but was hoping for something better that this:

```
// _.filter returns the entire element that matches name=who
_.forEach(_.filter( locations, { name:who } ), function(pv,pk){ 
    // returns the array of locations for "who" in 'pv'
    _.forEach(pv.location, function(value,key) { 
        // iterate through the location array one at a time
        console.log ( key+":"+value );
    })
});
```

Comment: Too long question. I bet no one will answer this. I suggest you to show the data you have and the desired result.

Comment: _but was hoping for something better_... I don't get it. We can get the locations from a matching `name` (using `_.filter`) and then iterate over the `location` values... but what exactly you want to do with `location` that you are looking for something better than `_.forEach`?

Comment: i guess you want `_.find(locations, 'name').location`, assuming name is unique

Comment: Something like @Maddy describes is what i was after to return the array part only rather than the entire matched element.  Otherwise, I use the code in my (edited) answer above.

Comment: @lealceldeiro - edited question with my version of an answer that works but does not look optimal.

Comment: I think Chris' answer is what you're looking for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you need, so two options follow, neither requiring lodash:

```
const locations = [{name:"dave", location:["home","work","pub"]},
                  {name:"alice", location:["school","college","university"]},
                  {name:"fred", location:["us","uk"]} ];


// Will work even if you have multiple Freds in your data you could also 
// use filter + map here, but reduce does it one shot
//
const allMatches = (name) => {
    return locations.reduce(((memo, entry, index) => {
      if(entry.name === name) {
          memo[name] = entry.location;
      }
      return memo;
    }), {})
};

// If you know you will only have a single "Fred", then it becomes even simpler
//
const singleMatch = (name) => {
    return locations.find(entry => entry.name === name).location;
};


console.log(singleMatch('fred'));
console.log(allMatches('fred'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// _.filter returns the entire element that matches name=who
_.forEach(_.find( locations, { name:"fred" } ).location, function(value,key){ 
    // iterate through the location array one at a time
    console.log ( key+":"+value );
});
```